# Android Studio, Cannot run Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Whenever i try to run an emulator i get :

```
16:35   Gradle build finished in 58 s 596 ms

16:35   Emulator: Screenshot failed to find cb 0

16:35   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have tried re-installing AS twice and ran on several different virtual devices and APIs.

Answer (score 9):

Do you have Valorant installed?

If so try disabling vanguard anti-cheat with elevated cmd;

```
sc config vgc start= disabled
```

And restart your PC after that
Disabling the anticheat will probably block you from playing the game so you can enable it again with

```
sc config vgc start= system
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunatly.
When i tried to run the project i got 
12:49 Emulator: C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

12:49 Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

12:49 Emulator: Screenshot failed to find cb 0
So i went to AVD manager and wiped data and tried to cold boot, And now i get:
Emulator: Screenshot failed to find cb 0

Comment: Do you have valorant installed?

Comment: Sorry, yes i do. I also went to msconfig and unchecked vanguard from autostart before restarting my computer.

Comment: Actually, I haven't disabled it from the startup. It is still enabled there. I disabled it from the services. If you want me to, I can try helping you out with anydesk

Comment: Same here. Installing valorant cause to this. So I uninstalled game. Now its ok.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i didn't have to uninstall the vanguard anti cheat, i just install another AVD with another android version (android 10 in my case) and that's it. or you can just run the app in your smartphone. Let me know if that helped"

Answer (score 0):

Disable Vanguard

```
sc config vgc start= disabled & sc config vgk start= disabled
```

Disable and stop Vanguard

```
sc config vgc start= disabled & sc config vgk start= disabled & net stop vgc & net stop vgk & taskkill /IM vgtray.exe
```

Enable Vanguard

```
sc config vgc start= demand & sc config vgk start= system
```

Enable Vanguard and restart your computer

```
sc config vgc start= demand & sc config vgk start= system & shutdown /r /f /t 00
```